# How to branch indoors grown mango?

Tags: fruit-trees, indoors, pruning, branches, mango

I have this mango tree, which is about 7-8 years old and 150cm - 200cm high. But it's still not branching, still only growing a new straight trunk.

How do I make it to branch a bit? Should I prune it? If yes, how much should I cut down?

[image: My mango]

Also, I grow it indoors, because it definitely would not survive our winter (-15 C°). But I am considering getting it out for summer. However, I did try to put it out 2 years ago in April or so, and a few leaves got burned. When is a good time to put it out? Or better not? I don't want it to die, it's my long-time friend already. :)

Comment: You are asking two completely different questions here.  They should be asked separately.  In this case, someone has already posted an answer to the second question, so I suggest that you change the Title to match that answer and you completely remove the question about branching. Then ask the branching question as a separate post.

Answer (score 1):

I’m happy to come across your post, I've never grown mango, but I know in Michigan it was quite easy to do sunflowers this year, even transitioning them indoors/outdoors.

I suggest starting to put them out around April/May and watch weather highs and lows, and where the sun mostly is throughout the daytime.
Since they are in a pot, put them in an area that keeps the least amount of sunlight, either front yard or back. Then bring them inside on cold nights. Also watch out for any bugs and pests that linger on the leaves, this may have caused the dehydrated leaves. Try using very little “insecticide spray” once every other day.

Don’t give up on your friend! They’re standing tall. Until you can move to a warmer area where you can plant them in the ground (their roots may also be stunted in the pot), I suggest doing this and getting back to me!
I am curious how they are since then, can’t wait to hear back from ya!